# What could I miss from Hibernate Session when working with JPA Entity Manager and vice versa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, jpa

I assume for sure some of you will immediatly check this question as duplicate, but really, I am trying to find meaningful insight and I don't find it (even in google, dont' find a clear answer)

The thing is, I know I can fetch the underlying Hibernate session from the Entity Manager, but I simply want some good link, voices from the expeirence or whatever addressing THIS specific doubt in a clear and focused manner:

> - What can provide EntityManager that Hibernate Session can't and otherwise? (from the point of view of logic and API)

So far if I am not wrong, I infered from other questions that Hibernate Session has some unique @filter annotation and EntityManager has a presumably unique @Pre/PostPersist/Update. Another issue is that this posts are sometimes old, and you'll never know what Hibernate version or JPA standard are they comparing.

I just want to understand to read the appropated relevant apis and everything before I start actually coding, and I am new to Hibernate/JPA.

I am going Hibernate 4.0 and JPA 2.0 through HibernateTools, in case that is important when comparing features or advantages.

A good resource from experienced users addressing the topic in a way nice for those who can judge with experience would be enough to make my day

Comment: Use the standard JPA API. Even Hibernate developers recommend it.

Comment: Then I infer that hibernate is dead if its only useful as a JPA standard provider?

Comment: Why would it be more dead than any other JPA provider? They all have their strengths and weaknesses. They all have their extensions to what the spec provides. They're all bundled by default in a container or another. Is General Motors dead because their cars all have 4 wheels, a steering wheel and pedals like all the other cars of all the other manufacturers?

Comment: Well, General motors precisely tries to give added value in respect to other brands, wheereas here someone is asserting that nobody should care about what can add Hibernate. Besides, it's not specially performant, that could be the only thing I can think of differentiatign among standard imlpementations. GM would be dead in the long time probably in case the spec says theyre cars have to be exactly like any other one. I guess the default provider of each IDE would end up eating up any alternative around. Just my humble opinion

Comment: Then I want to know which are the strengths and weakness over standard JPA, that was precisely the purpose of my question

Comment: On top of the standard JPA API, Hibernate adds specific annotations (look at their javadoc), additional mapping capabilities, Envers, Hibernate Search, etc. Re-read your own question. You didn't ask what Hibernate provides that other JPA providers don't. You asked what you gain or loose when you use the standard JPA API vs. the native Hibernate Session API.

Comment: But isn't the EntityManger - Session the top level object and logical point of departure for managing most of the things, like a jdbc connection wrapper? And that is standarized. What else can I play with usign JPA interface that gives me particular Hibernate features (wo. getting the session object)?

Comment: Anyway if I did bad assumptions, I appreciate a formal answer so I can vote you for your attention and priceless help :)

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of using JPA is that you are using a standard that can be implemented by different suppliers. As such you get the option to exchange the various implementations without (or with few) changes to your own application code.

If you don't care about switching suppliers, it really doesn't matter whether you use the Hibernate specific API or the JPA API. However, for day-to-day usage, the APIs are comparable, so why not go for the standard?

Comment: Because I want to understand what can hibernate offer me out of any provider. What they are trying to make me see I think, is that there is a bunch of extras not directly related with session/entitymanager management which still are not out of the standard's scope, or that is what I am understanding

Comment: Questions remain whether (1) you think you need those functionalities and (2) whether you think you may need to change persistence providers. Those questions (and the importance of the answers) we cannot answer for you.

Comment: I understand but still I don't know what these extras are :p

Comment: I used both in normal day-to-day applications and I don't see much difference. Maybe the hibernate API is sometimes easier to use in complex queries, but in practice these are hardly ever needed. I personally would go for the standard and if you ever appear to be in need of the special functionalities, use the special ones in that case. There is IMHO nothing wrong with sometimes using a combination of solutions.